# Incorrect p2 metadata after snapshot removing in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, tycho, p2

We're using "Remove Snapshots From Repository" task on daily basis with our repository in Nexus.

After snapshots removal is finished, we run a maven build with Tycho plugin which uses the repository in Nexus through Nexus P2 Bridge Plugin.

The issue is that it looks like Nexus don't refresh p2 metadata after snapshots removal. We have version 0.4 of our jar (it's available on disc and we can see it from Nexus UI), but when maven gets artifacts.xml from the repo, there's only 0.3 version.

Should we rebuild the p2 metadata somehow after snapshots are deleted?

Comment: Have you scheduled to refresh metadata ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes, after all I did it and it solved the issue. But shouldn't that metadata refresh happen automatically? In general I can't determine how much time the first task will take to set the refresh task to run with the minimum interval.

Comment: Which version of Nexus do you use? OSS or professional?

Comment: I'm evaluating a professional version 2.11.2-04

Comment: You should check if this intended or if there exist an issue for that...ask the sonatype guys...